# A Beamer Query - How to prepare a slide with a picture on left and text on right?

Tags: beamer

Dear friends: In powerpoint, it is easy to choose a layout for one slide with double columns, where we may place a picture on the left column and some related text on the right column. (See example in the image). How to prepare such a slide in Beamer? Any hint will be highly useful.. Thanks a lot!

[image: Ramanujan-Talk]

Comment: Use the `columns` environment. See https://www.beamer.plus/Structuring-Presentation-The-Local-Structure.html#sec-12.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `columns` environment. Here is a simple demo:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{5cm}
      \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image.pdf}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{5cm}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item one
        \item two
        \item three
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for great help! It works like a magic!